# Filter search on multiple words, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, search, filter

I want to filter my results better in my search bar.

I have my array contains:

```
[["object": "Ball", "color": "Red"], ["object": "Ball", "color": "Blue"], ["object": "Square", "color": "Red"]]
```

When I search Ball all the balls appear, but when I add Red (Ball Red) then it shows the square also, I want it to only show an object that contains both words Ball and Red, not show all that contain just one of the word Ball or Red. can this be done?

Below is my code.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {


        let splitText = searchText.split(separator: " ")
        filteredVehicles = posts.filter {
            if let s = $0["object"] as? String, splitText.index(of: Substring(s)) != nil {
                return true
            }
            if let s = $0["color"] as? String, splitText.index(of: Substring(s)) != nil {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
}
```

Comment: Your two `if`, do a "if  a and b", not to consecutive if with no relation.

Comment: try this objects.filter{($0["object"]?.contains("Square") ?? false) && ($0["color"]?.contains("Red") ?? false)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this you can also achieve a search with inverse order ("Blue Ball" -> "Ball Blue").

```
let splitText = searchText.split(separator: " ")
let filteredObjects = objects.filter {
    var include = false

    for text in splitText {
        if let s = $0["object"], text.contains(s) {
            include = true
            continue
        }

        if let s = $0["color"], text.contains(s) {
            include = true
            continue
        }

        return false
     }

     return include
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time on this @Oxthor. this worked perfect for me, I did have to change it slightly by adding as? String `$0["color"] as? String` to make it work. Thank you again for this. All the best

Answer (score 0):

**1. Update your filter condition like this**

```
let filter = dict.filter {

var isPassed = false

let split = searchText.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)

if split.count > 1 {

    if ($0["object"]!.contains(split[0]) && $0["color"]!.contains(split[1])) || ($0["object"]!.contains(split[1]) && $0["color"]!.contains(split[0])) {
        isPassed = true
    }
} else {

    if $0["object"]!.contains(split[0]) || $0["color"]!.contains(split[0]) {
        isPassed = true
    }
}
return isPassed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following

```
let splitText = searchText.split(separator: " ")
filteredVehicles = posts.filter {

    if  splitText.count > 1 {
        return ($0["color"]?.contains(splitText[0]))! && ($0["object"]?.contains(splitText[1]))!
    } else if splitText.count == 1  {
       return ($0["object"]?.contains(splitText[0]))!
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time on this I was able to get this to work with Oxthors answer, But again thank you for your time